# Hide folder names or such?

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel

Okay, I have a cpanel account with unmetered everything (pay a bit per month), so I wanna host my forum on it etc

I have the domains as lets say

money.com
wordpress.com
forum.com

As I'll have to put everything in different folders for instance money will be in /m/ wordpress /w/ and forum in /forum/ or something. What I'm saying is, how do I hide the file so it'll look like money.com/m/ is actually money.com ??

I need to hide the folder name the contents are in so I can host multiple sites, therefore the site will look like its the only site on the host so I don't have to add a redirect for it to direct it to the folder?

Thanks guys, been trying for a while!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "cPanel account." That's just the software used to manage your hosting account, which is what you need to check on first. So first of all, to be sure: Does your host, and plan, even let you have multiple domains? Their knowledge base/help system should provide instructions on setting them up if so.

Answer (score 3):

Use add on domains in cpanel, and each one you add should add a new folder to 'public_html' where you can place your files.